# __enter__ and __exit__ on class level in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, class-method

I am unsuccessfully trying to get the magic `with`-statement methods `__enter__` and `__exit__` running on class-level:

```
class Spam():

    @classmethod
    def __enter__(cls):
        return cls

    @classmethod
    def __exit__(cls, typ, value, tb):
        cls.cleanup_stuff()


with Spam:
    pass
```

However, this will result in an `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 15, in <module>
    with Spam:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Is it possible to use the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods on class-level anyway?

Comment: Why would you even try to do this?  My advice is to use the with statement as intended.

Comment: I am intending to extend the peewee.Model class with a class-level cleanup capability.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`__enter__` and `__exit__` are special methods, and as such only work correctly when [defined on a object's type](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup), not in it's instance dictionary.

Now `Spam` is a instance of `type`, and `type(Spam).__enter__` and `type(Spam).__exit__` do not exist. Therefore you get an attribute error.

To make this work, the methods would need to be declared on the metaclass of the class you want to use. Example:

```
class Spam(type):

    def __enter__(cls):
        print('enter')
        return cls

    def __exit__(cls, typ, value, tb):
        print('exit')

class Eggs(metaclass=Spam):
    pass

with Eggs:
    pass
```

Now `Eggs` is an instance of `Spam` (`type(Eggs)` == `Spam`, and therefore `type(Eggs).__enter__` and `type(Eggs).__exit__` do exist).

However defining a metaclass just to use an instance of it as a context manager seems a little over the top. The more straight forward solution starting from your example would be to just use

```
with Spam():
    pass
```

Or if you want to reuse the same instance later:

```
spam = Spam()
with spam:
    pass
```

Comment: I think then that the @classmethod should not be needed anymore.

Comment: There is a difference in which class will be passed as `cls` with and without classmethod, with it will be `Spam`, without it will be `Eggs`, so while it's technically not needed, it's not the same.

Comment: +1 but please remove the `@classmethod` decorators.  The first argument to a metaclass method is *already a class*.  Decorating with `@classmethod` means you get the metaclass instead of the class, which is rarely what you want.

Comment: @Kevin Ok, removed it, you and @nneonneo are correct, it makes little sense to have it on the metaclass. This way the `cleanup_stuff` method could also be declared on `Eggs` and not only on `Spam`...

Comment: Nonetheless I need to use the class in any case, since stuff from class-methods needs to be cleaned up on the class's level. I don't use instances in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that CPython doesn't call a bound method like `instance.__exit__`, it seeks over instance type, doing something like `type(instance).__dict__['__exit__']` than calls it. And since `type(Spam)` is a special `type` object (not a `Spam` itself), it doesn't contain `__exit__` method.

I tried to workaround that using metaclasses, but wasn't successful. `__getattr__` doesn't work either.

See here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2545fdbd4b4a6a77b132fccf816578f59b609be5/Objects/typeobject.c#L1362

- Py_TYPE is similiar to `type(self)`
- _PyType_LookupId walks over `type(self).__dict__` (no `__getattr__` call here)

Python 2 implementation is different, but main idea about getting `type(self)` applies to it too